# Should rel=canonical be used for discount deals copy and pasted to new webpages?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, canonical-url, rel-canonical

We have a discount deal website like Groupon. When we have a new deal contract with our old business owner we have to copy and paste the details from the last deal into a new webpage for the new deal.

Should we use `rel=canonical`for the last deal's webpage to point to the new deal's webpage to avoid duplicate content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See each deal in itself is a new content even though it belongs to the same business owner/ deal provider.

So rel = **canonical should not be used**.

If the same deal is changed / renewed, then it should ideally be done on the same page/ already existing deal page and you can enhance its visibility on site.

If a new page is still required for above case, then you **should add a rel=canonical** on old/similar deal to pass authenticity of that page to new one. Or if old one is not at all required and you want to pass all its SEO - juice to new one, then better would be to **permanent(301) redirect from old to new**.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, yes. If the deal content is not new & the the business owner is  the same old one, better use rel=canonical.